# How to make a floating label which can move up when focus or has content in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, input, label

I'm trying to make an input group, when the input is focused or has content inside, the label will move up like this:

```css
input {
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  margin: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  color: #999;
  transition: .5s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

input:focus~label,
input:valid~label {
  top: -12px;
  left: 0;
  color: crimson;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <input type="text" required='' id="name">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <input type="text" required='' id="email">
  <label for="name">email</label>
</div>
```

However I don't know how to do it in React, also may I know how to not use the required in html and input:valid method in css, since I manage the validation through Formik form in js. Thank you so much!

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div className="form-group">

  <Field type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" onFocus={this.handleInputFocus} onBlur={this.handleInputBlur} className={formProps.errors.name && formProps.touched.name ? 'is-invalid form-control' : 'form-control'} />
  <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>

  <ErrorMessage name="email" component="div" className="invalid-feedback" />
</div>

<div className="form-group">

  <Field type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" onFocus={this.handleInputFocus} onBlur={this.handleInputBlur} className={formProps.errors.email && formProps.touched.email ? 'is-invalid form-control' : 'form-control'} />
  <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>

  <ErrorMessage name="email" component="div" className="invalid-feedback" />
</div>
```

Comment: In my opinion you have to make to css style, one for the "normal" form and one for the moved up form, and in some way you have to check if the form is filled or focused and in that case you have to change the css className to the style of the moved up form

Comment: aren't the inputs missing ?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you so much guys! I just find out a way to do this :D! However I'm not sure is there a better way to make the code cleaner for multiple inputs in Formik.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        name: '',
        email:'',
        nameActive: false,
        emailActive: false
    }
  }
  activateField=(e)=> { 
    console.log();
    this.setState({
     [`${e.target.name}Active`]: true
    })
   
  }
  
  disableField=(e)=> {
    this.setState({
      [`${e.target.name}Active`]: false
   })
 }

 disableFocus=(e)=> {
  if (e.target.value === "") {
        this.disableField(e);
   }
 }

 handleChange=(e)=> {
  this.setState({
   [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
  });
   if (e.target.value === "") {
      this.disableField(e);
   } else {
      this.activateField(e);
   }

  
 }
  
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
    <form>
     <div className="field-group">
     <label className={this.state.nameActive ? "active" : ""}>
       Name
     </label>
     <input
      className="normal"
      type="text"
      value={this.state.name}
      onFocus={this.activateField}
      onBlur={this.disableFocus}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
       name="name"
     />
     </div>
      
      
      
     <div className="field-group">
      <label className={this.state.emailActive ? "active" : ""}>
       Email
      </label>
      <input
      className="normal"
      type="text"
      value={this.state.email}
      onFocus={this.activateField}
      onBlur={this.disableFocus}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      name="email"
      />
     </div>
      
      
    </form>
   </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
input {
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  box-shadow:none;
  outline:none;
  border:none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
  width:100%;
}

.field-group {
  margin:100px;
  position:relative;
}
label  {
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:0;  
  color: #999;
  transition:.5s;
  pointer-events:none;
  
}

label.active {
  transform: translateY(-25px);
  transition:.5s;
  color: crimson;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the css approach you did in first example.

here is some plain js if it helps.

```js
  function updateinputfield() {
    var x = document.getElementById("apninput");
    if (x.value.length < 36) {
      x.style.width = ((x.value.length) * 0.63) + 'rem';
    }
  }

  function moveUpPlaceholder() {
    var y = document.getElementById("floatingLabel");
    y.classList.add("labelMoveUp");
    y.innerHTML = "Insert Your Code";
    y.style.color = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)";
  }

  function moveDownPlaceholder() {
    var x = document.getElementById("apninput");
    var y = document.getElementById("floatingLabel");
    if (x.value.length == 0) {
      y.classList.remove("labelMoveUp");
      y.innerHTML = "Ex. 953-123-444-323";
      y.style.color = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)";
    }
  }




  function getvalueofInput() {
    var x = document.getElementById("apninput").value;
    alert(x);
  }
```

```css
.form {
  background: #e4f1fe;
  width: 140px;
  min-width: 140px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #c5eff7;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  margin-right: 0;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.submitSpan {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  background: lightblue;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.34s ease-in-out;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13.33px;
  left: 12px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.inputcontainer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.labelMoveUp {
  top: -20px;
  left: 2px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.submitSpan:hover {
  background: lightgreen;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<br>
<span><p>Type a number inside this field </p></span>
<!-- dummy input text >  933-444-123-444-213-444-424-411-437 -->
<br>
<br>
<span class="inputcontainer">

<input type="text" value="" id="apninput" class="form" placeholder="" oninput="updateinputfield()" onchange="updateinputfield()" onfocus="moveUpPlaceholder()" onblur="moveDownPlaceholder()">
 
<span class="submitSpan" onclick="getvalueofInput()">Submit</span>

<span class="floating-label" id="floatingLabel">Ex. 953-123-444-323</span>


</span>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Cool effect! :D

Comment: @Ying i can't reply as a comment to your post need 50 reputation. the code approach you are using is similar to mine, which works but is for 1 item at a time. 

i think you need to pick all elements with the same id and trigger the js for each right now is for single input object... well mostly the 1st that loads at startup, others will get ignored.

Im really newby like myself when comes to array or multiple picking in plain js, but it should put you on the right track.